# I do not understand the chisq.test output

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I have three variables:

```
str(vw)
num[1:2500] 56 74 98 23 ...

str(autos)
num[1:2500] 29 34 57 21 ...

str(ask)
num[1:2500] 41 118 70 79 ...
```

The summary functions shows this

```
summary(vw)
Min  1st Qu   Median   Mean   3rd Qu.   Max
16   22       31       44.32  51        448

summary(autos)
Min  1st Qu   Median   Mean   3rd Qu.   Max
16   21       31       44.45  50        926

summary(ask)
Min  1st Qu   Median   Mean   3rd Qu.   Max
16   28       45       65.78  78        880
```

Standard deviation:

```
sd(vw): 39.35
sd(autos): 45.19
sd(ask): 66.86
```

So we see that "autos" and "vw" are quite similar, while "ask" is a little different. Doing a Chisquare test shows this:

```
chisq.test(ask, vw)
data: ask und vw
X-squared = 49850, df = 46517, p-value < 2.2e-16
Warning message:
In chisq.test(ask,vw): Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

The same test for "ask" and "auto"

```
chisq.test(ask, auto)
data: ask und auto
X-squared = 42232, df = 46003, p-value < 1
Warning message:
In chisq.test(ask,auto): Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Why is there such an extreme difference in p-value? Did I do something wrong?

What does these warning messages mean?

Comment: You are not conducting the test you think you are.  Please read the help page for `chisq.test`.  Then consider *looking* at the results of your computation.  Here's an example that might illustrate what's going on: `chisq.test(1:5,c(2,3,2,4,1))$observed`.

Comment: `chisq.test` is simply the wrong tool for what you seem to want.

Answer (score 0):

> So we see that "autos" and "vw" are quite similar

Careful: the numbers you just presented that get to this conclusion are about the *marginal* distributions of `autos` and `vw`. They don't address at all the joint distribution of `autos` and `vw`, or in any other way the relationship between them, which is what your $χ^2$ test examines. So there's no conflict here.

Comment: The chisq.test results of *"autos"* and *"vw"* is

**p-value = 5.099e-13.** That means that *"autos"* and *"vw"* is different, am I right?

Comment: Check whuber's comment above. But what I'm saying here is that the sense in which a $χ^2$ test tells you two variables are different doesn't have to do with marginal properties. It has to do with their relationship.